# Queue of array of characters

Tags: c++, types, stl, queue, char

```
include <queue>
using namespace std;
char msg[1000];
```

Now, I want to have a queue that can store 5 of this kind of msg. So, it is a queue of size 5 that contains 5 arrays of characters, each array can contain up to 1000 chars.

How can I initiate the queue? I tried this but it did not work.

```
char msg[1000];
queue<msg> p;
```

Comment: What did not work? compiler error?

Comment: @JoeMcGrath Thanks.  I did `deque<char*> QUEUE; while(1){ char msg[1000]; msg = newString(); QUEUE.push(msg); }`.  Then I found out that all the element in the queue will be same since they are referencing the same thing `msg`.  How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: std::vector may be better choice, just reread you question and saw the size of the character array.  If you are using it to store binary data, a `std::queue< std::vector <char> > msgs` is probably your best choice.

You cannot use a variable as a type. You could have a queue of character pointers though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

std::queue <char*> msgs;

int main()
{
    char one[50]="Hello";
    msgs.push(one);
    char two[50]="World\n\n";
    msgs.push(two);

    msgs.push("This works two even though it is a const character array, you should not modify it when you pop it though.");


    while(!msgs.empty())
    {
        std::cout << msgs.front();
        msgs.pop();
    }

return 1;
}
```

You could also just  use std::string and avoid mistakes. If you use a `char*` you want a function to add msgs to queue, they cannot be on the stack (ie you would need to create them with `new` or `malloc`) than you would have to remember to delete them when you processed the queue. There would be no easy way to determine if one is in global space, one is on the stack, or one was made with new. Would lead to undefined behavior or memory leaks when not handled correct.  `std::string` would avoid all of these problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

std::queue <std::string> msgs;

int main()
{

    msgs.push("Hello");
    msgs.push("World");

    while(!msgs.empty())
    {
        std::cout << msgs.front();
        msgs.pop();
    }

return 1;
}
```

If it is just 5 Standard messages, then `const char*` would be a decent choice,  but if they are always the same messages, you should consider a queue of integers that refer to the message you want. This way you could associate more actions with it. But than you could also consider a queue of objects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

std::queue <int> msgs;

int main()
{

    msgs.push(1);
    msgs.push(2);

    while(!msgs.empty())
    {
        switch(msgs.front())
        {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Hello";
        break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "World";
        break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Unkown Message";
        }

        msgs.pop();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did `deque<char*> QUEUE; while(1){ char msg[1000]; msg = newString(); QUEUE.push(msg); }`.  Then I found out that all the element in the queue will be same since they are referencing the same thing `msg`.  How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I am not sure what newString() is, but i think msg should just me a char* in this case... can you post what newString does in your question?

Comment: yeah. i figured it out.  `newString()` is symbolize a function that changes the vaule of the `msg`.  I used `char *msg = new char[1000];` instead and now it works

Answer (score 6):

```
struct msg {
  char data[1000];
};
queue<msg> p;
```

Comment: I had at first written `typedef char msg[1000];` but as Tomalak mentioned, that doesn't work with STL containers. Wrapping it with a struct fixes that, though something using `std::string` or `std::vector` might be more efficient, depending on the nature of the data.

Comment: Instead of creating a struct, you could use `std::array<char, 1000>`.  Which basically does the same thing but also gives you convenient functions.

Comment: Thanks for the note @BenjaminLindley. Part of TR1/C++11 I wasn't up to date on.

Answer (score 2):

`msg` is an array, not a type. And since arrays are not copyable, this is not going to work anyway. Why not a `std::queue<std::string>` instead?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a '#' sign in front of your include statement.

Secondly, when you declare queue, you put the type you want it to contain in the angle brackets (in your case 'char*'), not a variable name like 'msg'.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: I basically agree, except that it is not your job to "cancel out" someone else's right to vote. Is this really a "great" answer worthy of an upvote?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: since when did you get the impression that you are deciding on what other SO readers can and cannot do? anyway, i think even you understand that this is not cancelling someone else's right to vote. it is cancelling pure destructive work