# c++:Push an Array into a Queue But pop Only an int form it using std::Queue

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I want to write BFS Openmp in c++! in Bfs method i need to add an int array (Dynamicly Allocated)

```
1 int *ptrTempNeighbour;
2 queue <int > Q;
3 firstElement = Q.front();//return front element   
4 Q.pop();//pop an int
5 ptrTempNeighbour = new int[nodesArray[firstElement].numNeighbours];
6 //nodesArray[firstElement].numNeighbours is an int
7 #pragma omp parallel for
8 for(i=0 ; ...){
9 ptrTempNeighbour[i] = nodesArray[firstElement].neighbours[i];
10 }
11 Q.push(ptrTempNeighbour);//add an array to Queue
```

Line 11 isn't work now. I need to add(push or insert) an array to Queue , but in Line 3  i need only to return an int or in pop(Queue) method pop only one int.
I read how [can i store array to queue in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680140/how-can-i-store-array-to-queue-in-c) and [Queue of array of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408776/queue-of-array-of-characters)
In [can i store array to queue in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680140/how-can-i-store-array-to-queue-in-c) use this line

```
queue < int* > qq;
```

If i use this line instead of Line 2 in my program the line 3 and line 4 don't work correctly for me.this line return to me a vector not a single int.

!!!!Edit post!!!!

it's important for me to first add ptrTempNeighbour(0) to Q then add ptrTempNeighbour(1) to Q then ptrTempNeighbour(2) to Q and ...
I think that a priority queue is helpful , But i don't know how i use it!

Comment: This code seems to be badly copy pasted here. You create a new `queue` `Q` and directly `pop` from it without pushing elements in?

Answer (score 0):

An STL container can only hold data of a single type. Thus you can either add and remove arrays, or individual values. However, perhaps a Queue of Queues accomplishes what you're hoping to do:

```
std::queue< std::queue< int >* > qOfQs; // create a q of ptrs to qs of ints
std::queue< int >* p_q( new std::queue<int> ); //create a q on the heap
p_q->push( 1 ); // add data to the queue
p_q->push( 2 );
p_q->push( 3 );
qOfQs.push( p_q ); // add the dynamic q to the q of qs
p_q = new std::queue<int>; // create another q on the heap
p_q->push( 4 ); // add data to the queue
p_q->push( 5 );
qOfQs.push( p_q ); // add the dynamic q to the q of qs
qOfQs.front()->pop() // removes int with value 1
```

You would need to make sure there is data to pop, and when you're done with the queue of queues, you need to iterate through it and delete the dynamically allocated queues, or better yet, use smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer , but i want to add an array outside of loop , and it was important to me to add array ptrTempNeighbour[i] in order to a QUEUE (Q) , it's important for me to first add ptrTempNeighbour[0] to Q then add ptrTempNeighbour[1] to Q  then ptrTempNeighbour[2]  to Q and ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hugh White for Answer to me.It was very good idea but only use in serial code.

After i read some Articles ,I got that these functions **aren't Thread Safe** , so we can not use these function in parallel region.

Thanks again!